# ico moon font not display

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have use ico moon font for the first time in project.

My icomoon css files:

```
              @font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?nmzwdp');
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?nmzwdp#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?nmzwdp') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff?nmzwdp') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg?nmzwdp#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="inf-"], [class*=" inf-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;


  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.inf-chrome:before {
  content: "\ead9";
}

.inf-chrome{ text-indent: 0 !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

My primeface code for using icomoon font:

```
<p:commandButton   value="Temps3" icon="inf-chrome"
                                             style="height: 25px;width: auto;"/>
```

Finaly my ico moon font not display, please anyone give answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add inf class which should be common for all your icon in addition class inf-chrome which is specific to your button

```
<p:commandButton value="Temps3" icon="inf inf-chrome" style="height: 25px;width: auto;"/>
```

Comment: just I had changed class name inf- insteadof icon-(default class)                   for example, [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] ---> [class^="inf-"], [class*=" inf-"]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have `class` attribute:

```
<p:commandButton class="inf-chrome" value="Temps3" icon="inf-chrome" style="height: 25px;width: auto;"/>
```

In your CSS is selector

```
[class^="inf-"], [class*=" inf-"]
```

Is this necessary?

```
.inf-chrome {
   text-indent: 0 !important;
   background-image: none !important;
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

Also be sure that your icomoon font is properly loaded.

Comment: just  I had changed class name inf- insteadof icon-(default class).

Comment: for example,                                                                                                           [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]  ---> [class^="inf-"], [class*=" inf-"]

Comment: Please do you have any online example like JSFiddle or similar? There is nothing wrong if you use 'inf-' instead of 'icon-', but you must use CSS class that match your CSS selector, and be sure your path to your fonts is correct.

Comment: Please see my example https://jsfiddle.net/6ppur889/ .I use some online icomoon fonts. You must use your font.

Comment: I think that you just forgot to add class attribute: `class="inf-chrome"` Am I right? I don't know what is purpose of attribute icon (`icon="inf-chrome"`) but maybe it is not necessary too.

Comment: it's styleClass not class. the class attribute in jsf components determines the type of the object referred by the component.